# How to create and load a "scikits.crab.datasets" dataset from a file

Tags: dataset

I want to create a custom dataset from the Movielens data file. I know that it is already a there provided with skits.crab.datasets which can be loaded using datasets.load_movielens_r100k(), but yet for some reason I don't want to use it.

I want to create a dataset and load it using an expression like load_my_movielens_r100k() using the movilens 100k u.data file. Please help.

Thanks in advance